# Operators only allowed at global scope

Tags: swift2

I am writing an app which compares a sign on time to a block of times and then takes the number of sectors and then returns a duty limit.

For example, a sign on at 0035 for two sectors returns a duty limit of 1030.

This works OK in my Playground but brings up several compiler errors when transferred to Xcode.

Starting with "Operators are only allowed at global scope".

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

This is my code so far:

```
let dateMaker = NSDateFormatter()
dateMaker.dateFormat = "HHmm"

let FTL1 = dateMaker.dateFromString("0800")!
let FTL2 = dateMaker.dateFromString("1259")!
let FTL3 = dateMaker.dateFromString("1300")!
let FTL4 = dateMaker.dateFromString("1759")!
let FTL5 = dateMaker.dateFromString("1800")!
let FTL6 = dateMaker.dateFromString("2159")!
let FTL7 = dateMaker.dateFromString("2200")!
let FTL8 = dateMaker.dateFromString("2359")!
let FTL9 = dateMaker.dateFromString("0000")!
let FTL10 = dateMaker.dateFromString("0759")!

let SO = dateMaker.dateFromString("0035")
var sect = 2

func <(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool
{
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == .OrderedAscending
}

func >(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool
{
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == .OrderedDescending
}


if SO! == FTL1 || SO! == FTL2 || SO! > FTL1 && SO! < FTL2 {

    if sect == 1 {
    let FTL = "1400"
    }
    if sect == 2 {
      let FTL = "1315"
    }
    if sect == 3 {
        let FTL = "1230"
    }
}
if SO! == FTL3 || SO! == FTL4 || SO! > FTL3 && SO! < FTL4 {

    if sect == 1 {
        let FTL = "1300"
    }
    if sect == 2 {
        let FTL = "1215"
    }
    if sect == 3 {
        let FTL = "1130"
    }
}
if SO! == FTL5 || SO! == FTL6 || SO! > FTL5 && SO! < FTL6 {

    if sect == 1 {
        let FTL = "1200"
    }
    if sect == 2 {
        let FTL = "1115"
    }
    if sect == 3 {
        let FTL = "1030"
    }
}

if SO! == FTL7 || SO! == FTL8 || SO! > FTL7 && SO! < FTL8 {

    if sect == 1 {
        let FTL = "1100"
    }
    if sect == 2 {
        let FTL = "1030"
    }
    if sect == 3 {
        let FTL = "0930"
    }
}

if SO! == FTL9 || SO! == FTL10 || SO! > FTL9 && SO! < FTL10 {

    if sect == 1 {
        let FTL = "1100"
    }
    if sect == 2 {
        let FTL = "1030"
    }
    if sect == 3 {
        let FTL = "0930"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that code inside a class definition? In that case – as the error message indicates – you have to move the *operator* definitions outside of the class.

Comment: Thanks Martin R. That seems to have fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

you should write code out of class

```
class NewObject {
}
func >(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool
{
     return lhs.compare(rhs) == .OrderedDescending
}
```